# Prepend path to image src attribute

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I wanna to display images from my db dynamicly, I want to do this:

```
      <div class="col-lg-3 item-menu" *ngFor="let laptop of laptops">
              <span class="helper"></span>

              <img src="../../content/Laptop/{{laptop.iconFileName}}" />
              <p class="name-menu">
                {{laptop.name}}
                {{image}}
              </p>

       </div>
```

My `laptop.iconFileName` is only end of my src path, but this doesn't work. I can only do this:

```
<img src="{{laptop.iconFileName}}" />
```

or

```
<img [src]="laptop.iconFileName" />
```

but i can't add to this folders before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use property binding (so, your second option), and since you need to prepend a path, just use regular old string concatenation, note the single quotes:

```
<img [src]="'../../content/Laptop/' + laptop.iconFileName" />
```

Property binding evaluates *expressions*.

Though a cleaner way might be to write a helper method in your Component that rewrites these file names to prepend that common path so you don't litter your template with a bunch of `'../../content/Laptop/' +`.

EDIT I'm not really sure what `{{image}}` is meant to be inside that `<p>`, but I didn't address that.

Comment: ahh {{image}} was only to check path displaying in 'p' that is it correct

Comment: @FreeStyle09 Ok, this should do it.

Comment: yeah, concatenation, i forgot about it, but it's strange now, i have good path and still images are not loaded, when i write manually it works :/ weird

Comment: @FreeStyle09 Are you using `[src]` or `src` ?

Comment: <img [src]="'../../content/Laptop/' + laptop.iconFileName " />

Comment: @FreeStyle09 What does the Network pane of your devtools say? You'll be able to double-check that the request for the image (1) is actually made and (2) is made to the right place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166344/discussion-between-msanford-and-freestyle09).